# ElasticBeanstalk health shows as degraded after adding autoscaling notifications

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

I added a SNS topic notification for my autoscaling group

[image]

Basically this just posts to SNS Topic and a lambda function uses a webhook to post to a Slack channel. All works fine.

However since adding this notification (almost a week ago)
My ElasticBeanstalk instance health has been showing as 'Degraded':

[image]

and the 'Causes' just shows

`Auto Scaling group (awseb-e-rf8zhmbjwm-stack-XXXXXXXXX) notifications have been deleted or modified.`

My ec2 instances seem healthy, and my app is working fine afaik.

Why does it keep this 'Degraded' state? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had wrestled with the same issue for a few days, this is how I fixed it:

Beanstalk does not like it when you change any piece of your environment outside of the Beanstalk configuration (i.e. adding an SNS notification to your autoscaling group) after the environment was created.

What you can do is make all changes to your infrastructure that you want in place - including the SNS notification. Your Beanstalk environment will show as "Degraded" as you know. Then, clone your environment into a new one under your application and then delete the old Degraded environment. Beanstalk will see the cloned environment as unchanged, and will then set the Health status to "OK".